# dplyr calculate variable with mutate in grouped data.frame when the value refers to a different row (but contained in the same group)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to learn dplyr, but still with problems.

This is a fraction of my data frame (it has several hundreds of species instead of only the two species I copied ("sp"), and several more rows for each species):

```
> sp.df <- structure(list(sp = c("Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne adiastola", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa", "Adelophryne gutturosa"), scenario = c("pre", "rcp45", "rcp85", "pre", "rcp45", "rcp85", "pre", "rcp45", "rcp85", "pre", "rcp45", "rcp85", "pre", "rcp45", "rcp85", "pre", "rcp45", "rcp85"), year = c("totalPAT", "totalPAT", "totalPAT", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2015", "2015", "2015", "totalPAT", "totalPAT", "totalPAT", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2015", "2015", "2015"), area = c(27393.5432893358, 26302.7931114686, 23767.0566182264, 1132.11815818819, 1409.95821237362, 1367.22415806142, 1132.11815818819, 1431.32621046934, 1452.69684644667, 276.54858281478, 0, 0, 234.014708239003, 0, 0, 234.014708239003, 0, 0), area.period = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21.3679980957127, 85.4726883852542, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c("anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf", "anf")), .Names = c("sp", "scenario", "year", "area", "area.period", "group"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L), class = "data.frame")

> sp.df
                           sp scenario     year       area area.period group
1   Adelophryne adiastola      pre totalPAT 27393.5433          NA   anf
2   Adelophryne adiastola    rcp45 totalPAT 26302.7931          NA   anf
3   Adelophryne adiastola    rcp85 totalPAT 23767.0566          NA   anf
46  Adelophryne adiastola      pre     2010  1132.1182     0.00000   anf
47  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp45     2010  1409.9582     0.00000   anf
48  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp85     2010  1367.2242     0.00000   anf
49  Adelophryne adiastola      pre     2015  1132.1182     0.00000   anf
50  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp45     2015  1431.3262    21.36800   anf
51  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp85     2015  1452.6968    85.47269   anf
52  Adelophryne gutturosa      pre totalPAT   276.5486          NA   anf
53  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp45 totalPAT     0.0000          NA   anf
54  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp85 totalPAT     0.0000          NA   anf
97  Adelophryne gutturosa      pre     2010   234.0147     0.00000   anf
98  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp45     2010     0.0000     0.00000   anf
99  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp85     2010     0.0000     0.00000   anf
100 Adelophryne gutturosa      pre     2015   234.0147     0.00000   anf
101 Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp45     2015     0.0000     0.00000   anf
102 Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp85     2015     0.0000     0.00000   anf
```

What I want to do is, for each species, create a new column that has in all the rows of the species the result of multiplying 0.2* the value in area in the first row of the species (which could be filtered with `year=="totalPAT"` and `scenario=="pre"`). It is something that I would normally do with a for loop, like I do in the next example to illustrate the result that I want:
It should look like this:

```
> for (sp in sp.df$sp){
+     sp.df$goal[sp.df$sp == sp] <- 0.2*sp.df$area[sp.df$sp == sp & sp.df$year =="totalPAT" & sp.df$scenario =="pre"]
}
> sp.df
                           sp scenario     year       area area.period group       goal
1   Adelophryne adiastola      pre totalPAT 27393.5433          NA   anf 5478.70866
2   Adelophryne adiastola    rcp45 totalPAT 26302.7931          NA   anf 5478.70866
3   Adelophryne adiastola    rcp85 totalPAT 23767.0566          NA   anf 5478.70866
46  Adelophryne adiastola      pre     2010  1132.1182     0.00000   anf 5478.70866
47  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp45     2010  1409.9582     0.00000   anf 5478.70866
48  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp85     2010  1367.2242     0.00000   anf 5478.70866
49  Adelophryne adiastola      pre     2015  1132.1182     0.00000   anf 5478.70866
50  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp45     2015  1431.3262    21.36800   anf 5478.70866
51  Adelophryne adiastola    rcp85     2015  1452.6968    85.47269   anf 5478.70866
52  Adelophryne gutturosa      pre totalPAT   276.5486          NA   anf   55.30972
53  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp45 totalPAT     0.0000          NA   anf   55.30972
54  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp85 totalPAT     0.0000          NA   anf   55.30972
97  Adelophryne gutturosa      pre     2010   234.0147     0.00000   anf   55.30972
98  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp45     2010     0.0000     0.00000   anf   55.30972
99  Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp85     2010     0.0000     0.00000   anf   55.30972
100 Adelophryne gutturosa      pre     2015   234.0147     0.00000   anf   55.30972
101 Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp45     2015     0.0000     0.00000   anf   55.30972
102 Adelophryne gutturosa    rcp85     2015     0.0000     0.00000   anf   55.30972
```

But with these long tables, it takes a lot of time. I am starting to learn dplyr and have found `group_by` really useful for this king of stuff... but I still need to figure out how to do these more complex things...
I was thinking in something like:

```
sp.df %>% 
  group_by(sp) %>% 
  mutate(goal = 0.2*filter(year == "totalPAT"))
```

But

```
Error: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Maybe I am just using a weird format of table... I just need the goal in each species row, so later I can compare the values in the area column with this goal.
Thanks a lot if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be certain that your data.frame is sorted correctly, try:

```
sp.df %>% group_by(sp) %>% mutate(goal = 0.2 * first(area))
```

which uses `dplyr::first` to pick out the first within group.

Another option would be:

```
sp.df %>% group_by(sp) %>% mutate(goal = 0.2 * area[year == "totalPAT"][1])
```

picking out the areas such that `year == "totalPAT"` and from those taking just the first (by group).

Edit:
Some benchmarks:

```
lj <- function(x)  x %>% 
 left_join(x %>% filter( year =='totalPAT', scenario =='pre') %>%
 mutate(goal = 0.2*area) %>%
 select(sp, goal), by='sp') 

fir <- function(x) x %>% arrange(year != "totalPAT" & scenario != "pre") %>% 
 group_by(sp) %>% mutate(goal = 0.2 * first(area))

reptimes <- function(x) x %>%
 group_by(sp) %>%
 mutate(goal = (0.2 * area[year == "totalPAT" & scenario =='pre']) %>% 
           rep(times=n()))

bracket <- function(x) x %>% group_by(sp) %>% 
 mutate(goal = 0.2 * area[year == "totalPAT" & scenario == "pre"][1])

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fir(sp.df), bracket(sp.df), 
 lj(sp.df), reptimes(sp.df), times = 1000)

Unit: microseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
     fir(sp.df) 1480.502 1543.401 1755.633 1575.064 1651.837 20137.41  1000
 bracket(sp.df)  941.361  982.226 1178.849 1002.561 1045.390 19536.25  1000
      lj(sp.df) 1776.140 1856.851 2172.697 1906.072 1995.426 59463.52  1000
reptimes(sp.df) 1120.376 1168.362 1327.877 1191.406 1242.211 17540.17  1000
```

The moral looks like don't use the `left_join` or this silly `arrange` if you are doing this many times.

Comment: You could insure proper sorting by mutating year and scenario  into properly leveled factors then using `arrange`.

Comment: @Bishops_Guest good point, or `arrange(year != "totalPAT" & scenario != "pre")` before mutate, because who likes factors. Also you have a typo in your solution, should be `scenario == "pre"`, not `sp == "pre"`.

Comment: Thanks @TaylorH! This works just fine. It is true that it would be better not to depend on the sorting, neither to rearrange the rows... but it definately works!

Comment: @JavierFajardo I don't have enough rep to comment on someone else's answer but the second option in the above post is deficient in a few ways: 1, it is missing a close paren `)` at the very end, and 2, the `rep(n())` is useless, as the value from `area[year == "totalPAT" & sp =='pre']` is already recycled to the whole column by group. Try `sp.df %>%
 group_by(sp) %>%
 mutate(goal = (0.2 * area[year == "totalPAT" & scenario =='pre']))` or `sp.df %>%
 group_by(sp) %>%
 mutate(goal = (0.2 * area[year == "totalPAT" & sp =='pre']) %>% 
               rep(times=n()))`. Identical!

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if they are the same... the second fails to me. However, the first one works perfectly

Comment: @JavierFajardo sorry, copy-pasted the old, wrong code. Should be: `sp.df %>% group_by(sp) %>% mutate(goal = (0.2 * area[year == "totalPAT" & scenario =='pre']) %>% rep(times=n()))` (note difference `scenario == 'pre'` vs `sp == 'pre'`. Sorry for the confusion. Now those expressions should be identical!

Comment: Oh, right, how I did not notice that! Thanks for solving my question!